# content of the view not getting aligned to the center

Tags: android, android-layout

I have HTML content placed in my custom view. This content, I want it to get it placed in the center, with the heading starting from the top in the center.
If I put :
    android:gravity="center"
instead of 
    android:textAlignment="center"
the whole starts from the center and not from the top.
If I use the 2nd statement, the content is arranged to the left.
Here is the code:

```
 <com.example.acer.myapplication.ZoomView
    android:id="@+id/iop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"/>
```

Comment: Try adding `android:includeFontPadding = "false"`                                    
You can also try editing `android:gravity = "center_vertical|center_horizontal"`

Comment: Is your custom view inherit from TextView? What view group do you add this view in?

Comment: Custom view inherit from textview

Comment: On some phone it works fine. But for some devices gives such problem